# what does this operation mean?

Tags: summation

What does 
$$
E\left( RI \right) =\frac{\sum_i{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_{i\cdot}\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right) \sum_j{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n_{\cdot j}\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right)}}}{\left( \begin{array}{c}
 n\\
 2\\
\end{array} \right)}
$$
mean?

Comment: I'd be interested to see where that formula arose in the context of mathematical physics.

Comment: Actually,it is a formula in data science, my label is wrong.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Ah, I see. What's $RI$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the expectation of $RI$ is a product of two sums of binomial coefficients, divided by a binomial coefficient. In particular, $\binom{m}{2}=\frac12m(m-1)$ is the number of ways to choose $2$ distinct elements from $m$ if order is irrelevant.